# Individual links in blocks in a set to not disturb other links on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a forum category link guide. Something like [this](http://www.thefastlaneforum.com/community/forums/the-fastlane.21/)...

The place where it says: Forums > The Financial Roadmap

First - Whenever I hover over the link, it pushes the link one row down.

Second - How can I get blocks like in this forum where it has the outer right block?

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/) to show what it is doing and what I have...

I thought putting my hover to a block setting would help, but it did nothing.

How can I do this?

```
.forum_links_out {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.forum_links_out a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.forum_links_out a:hover{
    display: block;
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
.forum_links_out a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Remove `display: block;`...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "outer right block"?

Comment: @l19 I mean, the right > after Forums and The Financial Roadmap. How it is like Forums > The Financial Roadmap >

Comment: When I remove `display: block;` is now doesn't push the link to the next line, but the hover doesn't fill the entire container.... https://jsfiddle.net/b0txv2m2/1/

Comment: The [default value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) of `display` is `inline`, and you change it to `block` on hover, so what did you expect?

Comment: @Ralph It doesn't fill entire container because of 10px padding of parent div

Comment: @Cheslab How can I add padding to it then if it does that?

Comment: @Ralph add padding to an `a` element instead

Comment: @Cheslab I tried adding it to the `a:link` and I made a sole `a` element and neither worked for the padding.

Comment: How about some arrows like this? https://jsfiddle.net/u5aqfqxL/

Comment: @l19 I have arrows like that now in my `<?php echo "&gt";?>` I'm looking for something more like a CSS3 effect. Something that will be an actual element, just like in that link I posted.

Comment: Why don't you look at the code of the page you posted and see how they did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go - DEMO first:

```css
.forum_links_out {
    margin: 20px;
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.forum_links_out a {
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.forum_links_out a:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.forum_links_out a span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    top: 4px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 2;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
.forum_links_out a:last-child {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.forum_links_out a:hover, .forum_links_out a:hover span {
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
.forum_links_out a:visited {
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="forum_links_out">
    <a href='discussions.php'>Discussions Index<span></span></a>
    <a href='discussions2.php'>Computers<span></span></a>
    <a>Asus</a>
</div>
```

How it works:
[image]

Comment: Nice! This is the best answer I have seen yet on here. Very detailed and it makes complete sense! Let me try it really quick if you don't mind.

Comment: Worked great! I did those though because I think I want it this way...not too sure yet, but I added a blank <a></a> under my links so I had the arrow at the end of the last one as well. `<div class="forum_links_out">
    <a href='discussions.php'>Discussions Index<span></span></a>
    <a href='discussions.php'>Computers<span></span></a>
    <a>Asus<span></span></a>
    <a></a>
   </div>` In case any one ever needs to see that as well. Thanks!